# Meteor ShareJS document update/snapshot wipes out other values

Tags: meteor, ace-editor

I'm using the Meteor ShareJS package for concurrent editing. I am trying to write additional values to items in the docs collection. Things like titles, etc. It seems to work until a document is edited in the ACE editor to the point where a new snapshot is created. At this point all of the extra fields are cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the meteor-sharejs package.

The recommended way to use the package is to keep all metadata in a Meteor Collection, and not in the ShareJS docs collection. This is because they are basically separate software stacks that do not talk to each other. It's also possible that you are using a `docs` collection for your documents which is the same name as the ShareJS collection; then they would be overwriting each other.

If you'd like to see ShareJS not head in the direction of being compatible only with Derby, I'd encourage you to chip in at https://github.com/share/ShareJS/issues/277.

Comment: Thanks. Thats similar to what I am doing now. The problem I am running into is that I want to store snapshots of my documents to be able to explicitly revert back to. The snapshot field in the docs collection that ShareJS uses lags behind what is on screen (understandably so since it uses OT). Is there a way to force ShareJS to update its snapshot? If not what way would you recommend to keep my own snapshots?